# margin: 0 auto; Seems to work fine in Chrome/FF but, again, IE disagrees

Tags: css, layout, web

On my Joomla Website, I am using a template which uses the following CSS rule to make the content pane centred:

```
clear:both;
margin:0 auto;
width:920px;
```

This seems to work perfectly well in FF/Chrome, but when loaded in IE, all is glued to the left side of the window. What's the issue with this? margin: 0 auto; seems like a sensible, straight-forward rule. Why does IE not obey?

Comment: This should work as far as I know. Is the element a div, and is it displayed as a block? I know of ways to achieve this using positioning if you're not precious about the margin approach.

Comment: it's a div and display:block; I would not mind trying a different approach if it's within reasonable difficulty to reach the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your DOCTYPE does not look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!--  --><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

because then, IE will be in Quirksmode (no boxmodel)

Comment: Nope. that's not it. it's <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Maybe you can fix it making this: wrap a div around the div you want to center with text-align center and give the innerdiv text-align left

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the following:

```
position:absolute;left:50%;
margin:0 0 0 -460px;
width:920px;
```

which will center the div in its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it may help to expand the options explicitly:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```